# Jenkins - Problems with git in Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I install jenkins in kubernetes using Helm chart.

I create some task with MultibranhPipeline.

After few executions in all task I receive the following error:

```
Started by user admin
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to git@10.12.22.25:trayectorias-educativas/gateway-service.git
 > git config remote.origin.url git@10.12.22.25:trayectorias-educativas/gateway-service.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials codicengit-ssh-key
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 255:
stdout: 
stderr: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Invalid argument

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:365)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:325)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:391)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:582)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:293)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I try:

- change the method that init tasks ( push from gitlab, jenkins check
  every 1 minute and manually)
- delete and re-create the task a lot of times

But none of this worked.
The error appears randomly. Sometimes in the second execution or in the tenth

If I execute `rm -rf *` on the path `/var/jenkins_home/caches`, everything works again